# Ruby - Share local variable with the obj's eigenclass

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, eigenclass

I am trying to dynamically define methods on an initialized Ruby object `MyObject` based on a hash `my_hash` I pass to its `initialize` method. In the body of the `initialize` method, I have the following:

```
my_hash.each do |key|
  class << self
    define_method(key.underscore.to_sym) do
      my_hash[key]
    end
  end
end
```

This fails with a `undefined local variable or method 'key' for #<Class:#<MyObject:0x007fc7abw0cra0>>`. Any ideas why?

The `my_hash` is made out of a json response with a lot of camelized keys, so it's more convenient to have simple ruby methods to get the values I want.

Comment: Convert your hash to OpenStruct, that will create a method for each of your key.

Comment: But that won't make the methods available on the MyObject object would it? Unless I somehow redefine method_missing to pass the calls to the OpenStruct object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in. The (lexical) scopes in Ruby are script scope, module/class definition scope, method definition scope and block scope. Only block scopes nest in their outer scopes (aka close over their surrounding scope). So, you have to use a block:

```
my_hash.each_key do |key|
  singleton_class.class_eval do
    define_method(key.to_sym) do
      my_hash[key]
    end
  end
end
```

Or even better yet:

```
my_hash.each_key do |key|
  define_singleton_method(key.underscore.to_sym) do
    my_hash[key]
  end
end
```

Note: I also fixed a bug, you should be iterating the keys with `each_key`, not `each` (which is an alias for `each_pair`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`define_singleton_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method) rather than `class << self`. Also note that [`Hash#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-each) yields a two element array with the key and value.

```
my_hash.each do |key, val|
  define_singleton_method(key.underscore.to_sym) do
    val
  end
end
```

Comment: I'll upvote if you edit to explain the first sentence.